# Can we place JavaScript Code along c# in .NetCore WebApi

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-2.1, smtpclient

I have a method in my asp.net Core web Api that has for role sending Emails  , using **SmtpClient**.
the Body of the message is this html string:

```
  @"<html>
         <head>
              <style>
                   #modalHeader{
                        background-color:#6495ED;
                        color:white;
                        text-align: center;
                        height:80px;
                       }  
                        .example_b {
                                      color: #fff !important;
                                      text-transform: uppercase;
                                      text-decoration: none;
                                      background: #60a3bc;
                                      padding: 20px;
                                      border-radius: 50px;
                                      display: inline-block;
                                      border: none;
                                      transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
                                     }
                                    .example_b:hover {
                                            text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
                                            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
                                            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
                                            transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
                                            }
                                </style>
                            </head>
                      <body>
                        <p>Bonjour,<br> 
                            Afin d’authentifier votre connexion sur le système de prise de rendez-vous à distance de la " + Structure + @" Nous vous invitons à  confirmer votre mail en cliquant sur ce lien 
                         </p>
                    <div style='border:1px solid black'>
                          //<div id='modalHeader'>Confirmation d'Email</div>
                            //<br>
                                //<br>
                            <div id='modalBody'>
                              <div class='button_cont' align='center'>
                                <a class='example_b' href='" + url + "' target='_blank' rel='nofollow noopener'>Confirmer Votre Email</a>" +
                                "</div> </div> <br/> </div> </body> </html>";
```

as you see i m using ***a href*** to trigger a call to another method in service , the problem with that is that it opens to me a blank page each time i click the button , so the solution would be to add an event instead to the button using javascript.

My question is how can i add Js to c# code in asp.net core 2.1 ?
is adding just ***script tag*** inside the ***html tag*** would make the work of letting JS doing the work ?

Comment: what about removing target='_blank' ?

Comment: removing target would still open a blank page after the click on button  in the same modal of the email

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute javascript inside an email. This used to be possible in the 90's and early 2000's, but it is no longer possible.

Comment: so what is the alternative ? we can't link events for html content message

Comment: URL tracking links

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element in the email are you sure you see the correct url? 
If yes maybe it would be worth giving a try to inspect an href link in one email. I checked at the moment and I saw something like that: [image]
It could be worth the try...